# what is default value type of kotlin class constructor parameter?

Tags: oop, kotlin

```
class Greeter(name: String) {

    fun greet() {
       println("Hello, $name")
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Greeter(args[0]).greet()
}
```

for above program I got this error

```
Unresolved reference: name
```

but when I add var or val

```
class Greeter(var name: String) {
```

or

```
class Greeter(val name: String) {
```

then program works fine, so why I need to add var or val to name, what is default type for constructor parameter val or var and why program gives me error when I not mention var or val

Comment: Because adding `val` or `var` makes the parameter a _property_ as well. Without either keyword the parameter is only a parameter, and thus only accessible during initialization. See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors

Answer (score 1):

To use your value in the constructor like class Greeter(name: String), you can use init{}

```
class Greeter(name: String) {
    var string:name = ""
    init{
        this.name = name
    }

   fun greet() {
       println("Hello, $name")
    }
}
```

or If you use val or var in the constructor it is more like class level variable and can be accessed anywhere inside the class

```
class Greeter(var name:String){
    fun greet() {
       println("Hello, $name")
    }
}
```

The variable name can be used directly in the class then. 
We can also give default values for the variables in both cases.

Comment: "you have to use init{}" No you don't, it can be used directly in initializers too (`var _name = name`).

Answer (score 1):

Adding val or var makes the parameter a property and can be accessed in the whole class.
Without this, it is only accessible inside init{}

Answer (score 0):

The question is not making any sense, But the problem you are facing does make sense. In your case, the approach you are using is,

Wrong-Way:

```
// here name is just a dependency/value which will be used by the Greeter
// but since it is not assigned to any class members,
// it will not be accessible for member methods 
class Greeter(name: String) {
  fun greet(){} // can not access the 'name' value
}
```

Right-Way:

```
// here name is passed as a parameter but it is also made a class member
// with the same name, this class member will immutable as it is declared as 'val'
class Greeter(val name: String) {
  fun greet(){} // can access the 'name' value
}
```

You can also replace `val` with `var` to make the `name` a `mutable` class member.